# IDA pro Imports

Tags: python, ida

i have been delving into ida Pro for the last couple of weeks to get a bit of a background.

Something that has been bugging me for a long time though is the seemingly lack of support for pulling out the imported functions.

All i want is a script that can copy the entire imports window and paste into a text file, but I am having serious trouble finding anything in the API's that can help me do this. It should be very simple, yet I find it impossible. I have managed to find things to pull out the library's from this window, but nothing to pull out everything.

any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Something using openImports(), then a copyall would be fantastic. But I have no idea how to go about the copyall bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the assertion that you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> or `dumpbin`.

However, what you ask has been solved already by the IDAPython project and I suggest you head over and look at their examples ([here](http://code.google.com/p/idapython/wiki/ExampleScripts) and [here](http://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/Scripts/)), especially [this one](http://code.google.com/p/idapython/source/browse/trunk/Scripts/ImportExportViewer.py).

The relevant `idaapi` functions are:

- `idaapi.get_import_module_qty`
- `idaapi.enum_import_names`

Answer (score 2):

**GUI Solution:**

You can copy the entire contents of the imports window by placing focus on that window and hitting `Ctrl+Ins`.

**IDAPython Solution:**

This may need to be tweaked to your liking, but this should hopefully get you started:

```
text = ""
seg = SegByName(".idata")
for i in xrange(seg, SegEnd(seg), 4):
    text += "%08x %s\r\n" % (i, Name(i))
open(r"c:\imports.txt", "wb").write(text)
```

Comment: Fails if the imports are not in `.idata` ... and since this is a convention rather than a rule, you should fix that :)

Comment: I want to be able to use a script to do this, so that i can do it over multiple files, is there an easy method in which to script it?

Comment: @WillMarkey: My initial solution was a very basic IDAPython script to print the name and addresses, but I removed it in favor of `Ctrl+Ins` because I wasn't sure if you specifically wanted a script or not.  I'll put it back, but if all you want to do is dump imports via batch processing, you might prefer a tool like dumpbin.  (e.g., `dumpbin /imports myfile.exe`)

Comment: It doesn't like converting a python int to a C long here

Comment: Well, if you're not dealing with 32-bit addresses, you will need to alter the format string slightly to produce correct output.  The code snippet above is just an example of how the relevant IDC APIs might be used for your purposes.  However, using `idaapi` to get the imports is more robust, so you should use the APIs mentioned in @0xC0000022L's solution instead.